# Recovering Unsaved changes - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, save, recover

I unintentionally closed Eclipse withing saving a file as part of restarting the system. So I lost an entire day of work. I Googled for it and I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712505/help-recover-eclipse-file). For me, though it shows History of the files, when I select *Compare With > History* item, it shows `State is not valid or might have expired`. I am still hoping I have the history to recover, if I could find out how to bypass this error message.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a pretty old question.... and I don't know the answer (I'm afraid, there's no solution as I was looking for one - again - because of losing five minutes of work). I can't imagine working without saving every few minutes and pushing to a private remote repository dozen times a day (I rewrite the history when pushing for real).

Answer (score 1):

This just means that you didn't save the file and lost your content. If you had saved it you would probably be okay, but in that case you wouldn't have to be doing this. I think that you are going to have to dig down and re-work it. Moral of the story, save often, use a repository, or use a back up drive.